# Tab indentation under Eclipse/Aptana IDEs

Tags: eclipse, aptana, indentation

How to enable tab indentation under Aptana/Eclipse IDEs? I appreciate the way that my Emacs indents lines code by pressing TAB key independently of the current cursor's position.

Answer (score 9):

I usually cut some code and then paste it into its new place, when doing this the code has the same indentation that had before.

To fix it I do the following:

Select a block of code and press `<Tab>` (To move the code to the right)

Select a block of code and press `<Shift> + <Tab>` (To move the code to the left)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the middle of a line you can indent it by pressing `Ctrl+i`, and of course you can do it for a block of text by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl+i`.
If it is in java files, you can set many more formatting rules (`Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`) and you can set it to auto-format whenever you save by going to `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of eclipse (see [Eclipse actions](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-edit.htm&ei=ZnlrTr3RDonPsga-t-D0BA&usg=AFQjCNEeMOJGdciCSxpkdcmnKg6oEvu8_A&sig2=pHgV4dsH_tlpR3H8Wu9zKQ)) you will find and entry "Smart Indent Mode". If you press `CTRL + SHIFT + INSERT` when inside an editor, the modeline below should show `Smart Indent` instead of indent. The preferences of that mode are defined in `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing`. The checkbox in the section indentation for `Tab` says: "Tab key adjust the indentation of the current line".

That sounds pretty well, but it did not work for me :-( I did not find any indication of the bug database of eclipse that something is broken here. Perhaps it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Under Aptana, you can indent your code by taping CTRL + Shift + F.